# Show that if all orthogonal trajectories to a curve pass through the same point $P_0$, then the curve is a circle.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to show that if every orthogonal line to a curve passes through the same point $P_0=(x_0,y_0)$, then the curve (or a part of it) is a circle with center $P_0=(x_0,y_0)$.

I could find an idea of the proof using differential geometry theory, but I'm trying to solve this exercise from a problem set of differential equations.

What I know is that if some of the solutions of the equation $y'=f(x,y)$ satisfy the implicit relation $F(x,y,C)=0$, for a certain value $C\in\mathbb{R}$, then this is an uniparametric family of curves. Moreover, if $F$ is sufficiently smooth, we can obtain an ODE for the family if we derivate with respect to $x$:
$$F_x(x,y,C)+F_y(x,y,C)\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0.$$

If I want to find the family of curves such that intersect orthogonally another family of curves, knowing that two curves are orthogonal if their tangent lines are orthogonal, if $y=\phi(x)$ is a curve that verifies  that condition, the orthogonal family for the previous ODE is
$$F_x(x,\phi(x),C)-F_y(x,\phi(x),C)\dfrac{1}{\phi(x)}$$ since the slope $\dfrac{-1}{\phi(x)}$ makes a line perpendicular to another tangent line. I'm confused where to start, without knowing that it will be a circle, if I suppose it isn't a circle I come up to nothing. Any hint? Thank you.

Comment: If $(x,y)$ is any point on your unknown curve $\mathcal{C}$, then the line tangent to $\mathcal{C}$ at $(x,y)$ is orthogonal to the line connecting $(x,y)$ and $(x_0,y_0)$. This implies $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=-\frac{x-x_0}{y-y_0}$. Solution curves to this DE are readily seen to be circles centered $(x_0,y_0)$ by separation of variables.

Comment: @MatthewH. Thank you very very much for your response, I understand it know! :)

Comment: @AVK Yes, I edited the post, it isn't trajectories, it was lines.